# VGA splitter. need help displaying dual monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

I recently obtained a VGA splitter (similar to this [VGA Manual Monitor Switch Box Splitter 2 Port Way](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Manual-Monitor-Switch-Splitter-Port/dp/B002YXGQLS))

I've tried using it with a bigger monitor than my first, just to see if my computer can actually use it. Here is a screenshot of my problem.

[image: Screen shot of display.]

The box has 2 buttons on it, button 1, allows the display to be projected onto 1 monitor, while button 2 allows the display to project across the second. Not both, I'd like for it to display across both, and i understand that i need to activate it when i'm on 1 monitor, but how to i make it show?

Please answer without using many technical terms? I kind of new to this. Thanks!

Info - one monitor is 21" and the other is a lot bigger. My graphics card is Nvidia Geforce 645 (I'm pretty sure it can support this), my ram is 6 gb. (if this mattered.)

The display is not detected, even if both buttons on the vga splitter are pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The splitter you are talking about is a *manual* splitter. A manual splitter is basicaly an easier way of switching between two displays without having to move cables about. In effect it acts as a switch for one input to be sent to **either** output A **or** output B, it cannot be used to send the input to both output A **and** output B. *as a side note, if you are expecting to use both monitors independantly via this method it would not work anyway, all you will be able to do with a device like this is show an exact copy of the screen to both monitors*

If the card is the *GTX 645* it can handle up to 4 monitors, but i cannot seem to find a 645, GTX or otherwise, online that has VGA outputs? Only DVI + HDMI. Are you sure this is the card and/or ports you are using? The 645 should have more than enough video outputs to do what you are doing without having to resort to additional hardware.

Are you plugging your cable into the blue output on your *motherboard* rather than the output of your graphics card?

Comment: The GTX 645 OEM GPU provides one VGA output via DVI-I.

Comment: @DanielB I did consider this, but i'd be even more confused if OP was adapting DVI > VGA then trying to split the VGA rather than using their additional video outputs.. Still worth mentioning though i guess.

Comment: No, I’d say it’s a perfectly logical action for the less computer-literate. Combined with cheap monitors only having a VGA input, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Once windows detects you have multiple monitors it then gives you the option on how you want your desktop to be displayed ([Screen Resolution Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDLUn.png)). It sounds like this is beyond the scope of your hardware. I don't have experience with this particular hardware you have but I would suggest buying a dedicated graphics card with two monitor ports.